# Django messages framework, custom middleware and HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-templates, django-middleware

NOTE: rewrote question because of oversimplification which led to bad example code.

To test this, please make sure you have these settings in your hosts file:

```
test.local 127.0.0.1
subdomain.test.local 127.0.0.1
```

In settings.py, set the cookie to work across subdomains:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.test.local'
```

Then I have a piece of middleware that looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class AuthorizeAccount:

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.get_host() != 'test.local:8000':
            messages.error(request, u'No subdomain!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://test.local:8000/')
        return None
```

My template contains:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

You can test this by going to http://test.local:8000 on your dev server (expect no message) and by going to http://subdomain.test.local:8000 (expect a redirect to http://test.local:8000 and a message).

I do get the redirect but I do not get the message. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: What URL are you redirecting *from*? Presumably it's pointing to the same dev server?

Comment: Yes, I redirect from a subdomain to the main domain, and have cookies set to work across subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

Messages are associated with a user via the session. But the session ID is stored in a cookie - and cookies are domain-specific. Yet the whole point of your middleware is to redirect from one domain to another. After redirection, the user will get a new cookie on the new domain.

In other words, this can't possibly work as you have it now. The only alternative would be to put something in the GET parameters of the redirected request.

Comment: Oops, I over-minimized. Actually I am redirecting from a subdomain to the main domain, and I have my cookie domain set correctly. Fairly sure that didn't work either. Will try again asap and report back here.

Comment: +1 for spotting error in example. I updated the example, and my original question still stands.

Comment: Daniel, if you look at the modified example with the hosts and cookie settings, the cookies should be valid for both domain and subdomain. Would the messages/session still be nuked upon redirection?